# Why jQuery doesnt have a way to avoid DUPLICATE-LOADING of itself?

Tags: jquery

I frequently meet situations, when two plugins load `jquery.js` script in different places of `<head>` section.

My question is, why jQuery itself didnt incorporate avoiding itself from double-loading (i.e. in the start of `.js`):

```
if(typeof $ !== 'undefined' && typeof FORCE_JQUERY_RELOAD ==='undefined')  { return; }
```

or something like that, giving user an option to FORCE call, or avoid double-calls... because double calls frequently break sites..

Comment: `because double calls always break sites` Not always. There are valid cases for including different versions of jQuery in a single page, although I agree it should be avoided where possible. As with most things related to coding, caveat emptor should be applied

Comment: `caveat emptor` can you explain it more, with example? i cant understand..

Comment: I mean to say that the library shouldn't stop you writing bad code, you should do that yourself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor In this case, replace 'buyer' with 'user'.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, I cant fully agree with you, because in PHP(or in other languages probably), there are always such things:  `if (!class_exists('blabla')) {  Class blabla{} }` 
 ..............  so, developers incorporate to avoid double-calls.. and why not the #1 script, doesnt have that simple?  or let there was like this `if (typeof $ != 'undefined'   && typeof 'FORCE_RELOAD_JQUERY'==='undefined' )`

Comment: Because as I stated above, there are valid cases for needing to include two different versions of jQuery in the page.